Planning to rent my fully paid house for periods of 1-max 2 years. Any issue with it?
I own a fully paid house in NL (no mortgage). I would like to rent it for periods of 1 or max 2 years, every few years, and then go back living in it, once the rental contracts end.
I've heard that there might be some restrictions by the government, that could not allow me to do that more than a few times.
Is that true?

You will have tax implications as well

@NicolasFormichella Can you elaborate more?

Getting taxable income in a country where you don't hold tax residency (for most countries, residency is counted as 183 days and over of presence in a country in a year) may lead to issues on how and where you must declare it.

@NicolasFormichella Ah yes, of course. That's inevitable.


I've heard that there might be some restrictions by the government, that could not allow me to do that more than a few times.
Is that true?

Not quite.
Based on this report it seems the Dutch government is considering scrapping temporary rental contracts ((tijdelijke huurcontract) which have a maximum rental period of two years. The move would make indefinite contracts the norm again for many people.

And what happens if that's my first house (and I don't own others)? Shouldn't I be able to cancel a indefinite rental contract anyway?

@aneuryzm See for example https://wsadvocaten.nl/termination-lease-rental-agreement-lawyer-amsterdam/ You can find out more information via further research on the topic

Thanks. I think I found my answer: "If you rent the house in The Netherlands for a longer period or for an indefinite period, the landlord can only terminate the rent in specific cases which are mentioned in the DCC. For example, if he/she wants to live in the house himself/herself or if he/she wants to renovate the house, while it is not possible to continue the rent.". However I'm still wondering if I can do that every few years.
